# How to express SELECT FROM (INSERT INTO ... RETURNING) in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Context: I'm writing a system that needs to do a high volume of correlated inserts (coming from another DB which stores denormalised records, so I'm essentially splitting a single object into multiple sub-objects mapped in different tables). Since I know I will have millions of rows to write, I'm trying to batch the writes and do lookup-or-create of the referenced objects inline, without incurring a roundtrip for every single row while SQLAlchemy looks things up.

I have the following SQL query for the lookup-or-create portion:

```sql
WITH token_vals (git_branch, git_commit, git_tree_clean, extras) AS (
     (VALUES
        ('foo', 'bar', true, NULL::JSONB),
        ('bar', 'asd', true, NULL::JSONB),
        ('baz', 'bar', true, NULL::JSONB)
     )),
     existing_tokens AS (
     SELECT source_tokens.* FROM source_tokens, token_vals
     WHERE source_tokens.git_branch IS NOT DISTINCT FROM token_vals.git_branch AND
           source_tokens.git_commit IS NOT DISTINCT FROM token_vals.git_commit AND
           source_tokens.git_tree_clean IS NOT DISTINCT FROM token_vals.git_tree_clean AND
           source_tokens.extras IS NOT DISTINCT FROM token_vals.extras
     ),
     inserted_tokens AS (
     INSERT INTO source_tokens(git_branch, git_commit, git_tree_clean, extras)
     SELECT token_vals.* FROM source_tokens, token_vals
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
           SELECT id FROM source_tokens
           WHERE source_tokens.git_branch IS NOT DISTINCT FROM token_vals.git_branch AND
                 source_tokens.git_commit IS NOT DISTINCT FROM token_vals.git_commit AND
                 source_tokens.git_tree_clean IS NOT DISTINCT FROM token_vals.git_tree_clean AND
                 source_tokens.extras IS NOT DISTINCT FROM token_vals.extras
     )
     RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM existing_tokens UNION SELECT * FROM inserted_tokens;
```

It works fine with PostgreSQL 12. I'm now trying to express this in SQLAlchemy 1.4, and I'm running into a problem, since apparently `table.insert()` is not a valid `FromClause` so it cannot be used in a `union()`:

```py
st = SourceToken.__table__

st_vals = values(
    column('git_branch'),
    column('git_commit'),
    column('git_tree_clean'),
    column('extras'),
).data([
    ('foo', 'bar', True, cast(None, JSONB)),
    ('bar', 'asd', True, cast(None, JSONB)),
    ('baz', 'bar', True, cast(None, JSONB))
])

existing_cond = (
    st.c.git_branch.is_not_distinct_from(st_vals.c.git_branch) &
    st.c.git_commit.is_not_distinct_from(st_vals.c.git_commit) &
    st.c.git_tree_clean.is_not_distinct_from(st_vals.c.git_tree_clean) &
    st.c.extras.is_not_distinct_from(st_vals.c.extras)
)

st_existing = select(st).select_from(st, st_vals.alias('v')).where(existing_cond)

st_inserted = st.insert().from_select(st_vals.c, select(st_vals.c).where(~st_existing.exists())).returning('*')

st_all = st_existing.union(select(st_inserted))
```

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 169, in reload
    _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 604, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/mathrick/Dev/Cerebras/devinfra/grey-haven/grey_haven/model/mapping.py", line 80, in <module>
    st_all = st_existing.union(select(st_inserted))
  File "<string>", line 2, in select
  File "/home/mathrick/.pyenv/versions/grey-haven/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 4909, in _create
    return cls._create_future_select(*args)
  File "/home/mathrick/.pyenv/versions/grey-haven/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 4849, in _create_future_select
    self._raw_columns = [
  File "/home/mathrick/.pyenv/versions/grey-haven/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/selectable.py", line 4850, in <listcomp>
    coercions.expect(
  File "/home/mathrick/.pyenv/versions/grey-haven/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 200, in expect
    return impl._implicit_coercions(
  File "/home/mathrick/.pyenv/versions/grey-haven/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 242, in _implicit_coercions
    self._raise_for_expected(element, argname, resolved)
  File "/home/mathrick/.pyenv/versions/grey-haven/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 424, in _raise_for_expected
    return super(_SelectIsNotFrom, self)._raise_for_expected(
  File "/home/mathrick/.pyenv/versions/grey-haven/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/coercions.py", line 270, in _raise_for_expected
    util.raise_(exc.ArgumentError(msg, code=code), replace_context=err)
  File "/home/mathrick/.pyenv/versions/grey-haven/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Column expression or FROM clause expected, got <sqlalchemy.sql.dml.Insert object at 0x7f4cc0be25b0>.
```

Is there some sort of wrapper I could use to turn the `insert` into a selectable?

Comment: Have you tried grabbing the SQLAlchemy objects as an initial select, and then referencing the attributes in your new inserts? You can also do recursive inserts if you do a `DATABASE.session.flush()` (whatever your DATABASE object is) and get sequence IDs that way.

Comment: @user3832673: I don't believe I understand what you mean by "grabbing the SQLAlchemy objects as an initial select, and then referencing the attributes in your new inserts". Could you elaborate?

Comment: You said you were using SQLAlchemy. What I mean is to use your `session.query(Table_class).all()` call, and then use the objects that are returned, calling the appropriate attributes, in your inserts? When you create your model object using SQLAlchemy, and then do a session add and flush, you have references to the created ID, assuming it's a sequence.

Comment: @user3832673: I see. Thanks for the suggestion, but that won't work, since the whole point is that I'm trying to express this all as a single query that does all the lookups itself, to avoid roundtrips of SQLAlchemy having to fetch that information first. I have since moved to using a separate query that inserts all correlated objects first, so the query above can just look them up and doesn't need to `SELECT` from the results of `INSERT INTO source_tokens`, which sidesteps the issue.